# I am getting an error in React and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript

I am just learning React and I'm at a lose with this one. The tutorials I am watching are giving me the quick ES6 version of setting up arrow functions with implicit returns. Thank you for the help! I am getting no errors on webpack with babel-loader and eslint is giving no errors as well.

Here is the error:

Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`.

Here is the code:

```
const React = require('react')
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
const Landing = require('./Landing')
const ReactRouter = require('react-router')
const { Router, Route, hashHistory } = ReactRouter

const App = () => (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Landing} />
  </Router>
)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

and the page it's suppose to go to:

```
const React = require('react')
const Landing = () => (
  <div className='app-container'>
    <div className='home-info'>
      <h1 className='title'>svideo</h1>
      <input className='search' type='text' placeholder='Search' />
      <a className='browse-all'>or Browse All</a>
    </div>
  </div>
)

module.exports = Landing

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Vidflix</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

this is the HTML to go with it

Comment: can you post the html from the page you are inserting Landing into?

Comment: could you try making your <input> in the Landing component not self-closing?  In other words, change <input ... /> to <input ...></input>.  Technically an input is not supposed to be self-closing in HTML5.

Comment: You might also make sure that Landing is imported correctly.  If you change the format of your fat-arrow function from const Landing = () => () to const Landing = () => {... return () }, then you can assign Landing to a variable outside of the jsx that you're returning and check it in the debugger or something.